# Mount point getting drop and getting back automatically

Tags: networking, mount, samba, aws, administration

I have an SMB (v4.7.6-ubuntu) mount point which is used by 2 other machines in the same network (AWS). Sometimes that mount point is getting lost and again automatically coming back.
Whenever it is lost it is showing this for that SMB mount point:

```
????????? ? ? ? "mount point"
```

Other mount points are intact. No lost issue. I have used the 10gbps bandwidth of AWS (c5.xlarge).Ubuntu 18.04lts.
After disconnect that particular mount point. the error is resource is busy.

Why is that happening?

Comment: DETAILS!! What version of Ubuntu? How are they mounted? No way to help with no details.

Comment: What's the configuration of the mountpoint? Are there any relevant error messages from logs?